# Converting a string with 2 point types to a list of points

Tags: haskell

I am writing a method that will take a string that that has 2 Point types in it.
Point types read (x,y) and the string that this method takes in will have 2 points separated by a single white space. I need to take these 2 points and separate them into a list.  I've been trying to get it to work with splitOn with no success.  Should I being using splitOn or is there a better way to do this?

exm. "(2,0) (2,3)"

list = [(2,0),(2,3)]

```
type Point a = (a,a)

-- Convert a String with points separated by spaces to a list of Points.
toPoints :: String -> [(Float,Float)]
toPoints s = splitOn " " s
```

Comment: `toPoints = map read . words`. Note this will fail badly if your input is malformed and it needs a type signature.

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you. Gave me exactly what I need.